# grep or awk truncate text in pipe

Tags: awk, makefile, grep

I'm trying to write a Make command to pause all dags. Here is what I prepared

```
for dag in $(shell docker exec -it airflow-webserver-1 airflow dags list | awk '/False/ {print}' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1); do \
    docker exec -it airflow-webserver-1 airflow dags pause $$dag; \
done
```

It works perfectly fine for short dag names. However, if a dag name is longer than 22 characters, then the dag name is truncated to only 22 characters hence `airflow dags pause` will fail because it can't find the dag name.

I have tried `grep 'False'` as well but it behaves the same.

For example: `airflow dags list` returns the following dag entry:

```
dag-exa-mple-lon-gnames        | dag.py        | dag-owner                  | False
```

After `awk` or `grep`, it will becomes:

```
dag-exa-mple-lon-gname        | dag.py        | dag-owner                  | False
```

Note the last char `s` is removed from the dag name as it's the 23rd char.

As suggested by @Mark Setchell in comments, I did  `| cat -vet` and found that the truncated charecters are actually moved into separate lines with empty values in other columns and the alignment are pretty off too. I wonder what `^M$` chars represent? **You'll need to horizontally scroll a lot to see the complete output**

```
 ^M$
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          dag-exa-mple-lon-gname | dag.py    | dag-owner             | True  ^M$
                                      s                   |                        |                       |       ^M$
```

Could anyone advise?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do share output of docker command and final output so that we can try to write command and could test it also on your sample input(basically output of docker command), cheers.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It has now been added as examples.

Comment: Do you mean `echo "dag-exa-mple-lon-gnames        | dag.py        | dag-owner                  | False " | grep 'False'` drops the 23rd `s`?

Comment: That's right. Both `grep 'False'` and `awk '/False/ {print}'` drops the 23rd char `s`

Comment: It sounds like you may have some mad characters in your output. Try `airflow dags list | cat -vet` and see if there are carriage returns or things other than alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, you're quite right. I have added some more output into the post itself. Some strange `^M$` chars are completely throwing it off.

Comment: You can delete them by piping through `... | tr -d '\r' | ...`

Comment: Thank you, @MarkSetchell. Managed to fix the issue by doing `airflow dags list -o plain`. The issue is caused by airflow output dag list as a table by default and tries to move longer test into next line to keep the column width consistent.

Comment: Regarding `You'll need to horizontally scroll a lot to see the complete output` - alternatively, you could come up with an example where we don't have to scroll so it's a bit more work for you but a bit less work for all of us trying to help you.